# Supressing duplex for single pages in PDF

Tags: pdf, printing, pdftk, duplex

I have several documents (PDF, source available), some of which have an odd number of pages. I'd like to merge them (no problem so far with pdftk) and make sure that each document begins on a new piece of paper even when using duplex mode for printing.

The duplexing should be disabled for each last page of a sub-document with odd pages.

How is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just insert a blank page after each document with an odd number of pages. Assuming that you have a PDF consisting of a single blank page named `/path/to/blank.pdf`, the following will do it automatically.

```bsh
pdftk $(for i in *.pdf; do echo $i; pdftk $i dump_data | perl -ne 'print "/path/to/blank.pdf\n" if (m/NumberOfPages: (\d+)/ && $1 % 2 == 1)'; done) cat output merged.pdf
```

Comment: I thought of something like this myself, thanks for the exact script. There is however the problem of blank pages without duplex...

Comment: I must have read your question too fast. Do you mean you would like a single document that will print differently depending on whether it is sent to a duplexing printer?

Comment: That would be the perfect solution, but I fear that this is impossible. I'm fine with two versions of the bundled file.